# Preventing Indirect access to website in PHP

Tags: php, security

I have a query. Is there a way to detect whether the website is accessed directly or in-directly? Let me make my question more clear to you with an example.

Let's say I have an Image sharing website. When an user opens the website and views an image, it adds to the total impressions of the image. But I have seen people embedding DIRECT image Url in the forums instead of thumbnail code so as to increase impressions. This is supposed to be an indirect access to the website which I want to prevent.

I simply want a solution that allows the website to be viewed only directly and not via false embedding of URL in forums, or via iFrames, or etc.

Is there a solution for this in PHP?

Comment: You could look at the referrer but that will only go so far as that is very easy to spoof.

Comment: use `.htaccess` to prevent linking directly to images from a host that is not your own, that way you can use your `.php` script to produce the actual image.

Comment: @jacobwalker0814: I think you'd have to have some pretty unique content to warrant spoofing.  Seems like the kind of thing you'd wait to become a problem, rather than spend a bunch of cycles on while you're getting started.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer the issue is tagged with 'security' and I don't know what all is entailed by the 'impressions' count. If there is some gain to arbitrarily boosting your own impression count then it might be desirable for a user to do so

Comment: Well, we could be VERY secure, and require only authenticated sessions, or better yet match the DNA in stool samples. There's always a tradeoff between usability and cost.  The referer header will get the 80% solution to get a service running.  When there's revenue, but a drag on service then spend the money.

Comment: The reason to implement such a solution is that users will be paid based on the impressions count. So, I would not like to pay for fraud impressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent [Hotlinking](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotlinking) of your images. I quote

> Hotlinking is a term used on the Internet that refers to the practice of displaying an image on a website by linking to the same image on another website

Add the following to your `.htaccess` file and change the domain as required.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: Yeah. This solution is correct and was recommended by many people. It will prevent users to use bandwidth. However you should allow them to use a low resulation version of the image with the same url.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I hotlinking prevention is not what I am looking for. I already have that solution in place but I want to know can we prevent a website URL for getting embedded in an forums BB code.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking then. You can't prevent me from embedding you image url anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the `HTTP referer` header.  While this can be spoofed, it's the easiest way to go.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer